# Networking lost after update from Debian Wheezy to Jessie

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I am currently setting a Virtual Machine for development purposes. I did a big part of this configuration under Wheezy, but I need some debs that were available only on Jessie.

So, I've updated the sources.list and did a dist-upgrade.

Everything went well, but after the reboot, I noticed that I lost all the networking. Repositories are unreachable, as well as a simple ping google.fr returns nothing.

What can I do to quickly restore networking so that I can continue my working.

I have a poor connexion and can not afford to download the whole install DVDs.

```
root@vm~# ifconfig
lo    Link encap:Boucle locale
      inet adr:127.0.0.1 Masque:255.0.0.0
      adr inet6::1/128 Scope:Hôte
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric 1
      RX packets:452 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:452 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 lg file transmission:0
      RX bytes:164238 (160.3 KiB) TX bytes:164238 (160.3 KiB)

root@vm~#
```

I am running VMware 1.0.1 build 1379776 and the last update of Jessie (debian 3.14.4-1)

Solved !

I solved it by add the following in `/etc/network/interfaces` :

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Try using a different network adaptor type in the VM config; it looks like it's not being recognised by the jessie kernel.

Comment: I've tried all the adaptors. I also tryed    
    /etc/init.d/networking restart

No change :-/

Comment: Try updating the vmware tools on that VM.

Comment: I solved it by add the following in /etc/network/interfaces :
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

Comment: If you want to install a single package  in Debian, you do not need to update the whole system. It can be done with three commands by inserting the repos for Testing and Unstable in /etc/apt/sources.list, fixing the distro you (mostly) wish by setting  *APT::Default-Release "stable"* in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/local, then doing *aptitude install packagae_name/testing -t testing*.

Comment: MariusMatutiae : Thanks a lot ! I didn't know this exists !

Comment: Why people are downvoting this question 3 YEARS later ?

Answer (score 0):

I met a similar problem and solved it by removing .dpkg-new suffixes from script names in /etc/wpa_supplicant. Maybe it would be useful for somebody.